# Adapt array of column widths to fit Bootstrap grid system

Tags: php, arrays, regex, twitter-bootstrap, closest

I am working on converting a system to Bootstrap grid, and the problem I have encountered is how to **convert the current widths from an array in PHP to the closest/"best fit" in Bootstrap?**

[See phpfiddle demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bd5e7bc7c35605e36d903fbf946010305d6c98c)

The idea is to base the new Bootstrap column widths on the old values, sadly the old database has some weird values I need to adapt to. Here are six examples of what the string of the old column widths and the number of cols can look like;

1. `%30,%40,%30,%` | `3`
2. `%,%,%,%` | `4`
3. `180,1070,,` | `2`
4. `20,80,,` | `2`
5. `75%,25%,20%,` | `2`
6. `,,,` | `1`

PHP code:

```
// example of output from database
$numberOfColumnsFromDatabase = 3;
$stringFromDatabase = '%30,%40,%30,%';
// NOT WORKING as intended:
// 3 cols with string '%30,%40,%30,%'
// Working as intended:
// 2 cols with string '180,1070,,'
// 4 cols with string '%,%,%,%'
// 2 cols with string '75%,25%,20%,'
// 1 cols with string ',,,'
echo 'Original string: "'.$stringFromDatabase.'"'."\n";

// strip percentage and explode to array
$stringStripped = str_replace('%','',$stringFromDatabase);
$columnArrayOld = explode(",", $stringStripped);

// only use the amount of columns from database
$cols = $numberOfColumnsFromDatabase;
$arrayShortened = array_slice($columnArrayOld, 0, $cols);

// sum it up
$fullWidth = array_sum($arrayShortened);
echo 'Full width = '.$fullWidth."\n";

// valid Bootstrap widths
$arrayToSearch = array(8.3, 16.6, 25, 33.3, 41.6, 50, 58.3, 66.6, 75, 83.3, 91.6, 100);

// calculate % of full width
$columnArrayStripped = array();
$columnArrayNew = array();
if($fullWidth > 0){
  foreach($arrayShortened as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $arrayShortened)) {
      if ($columnArrayOld[$key] == '') {
        break;
      } else {
        $percentage = round($arrayShortened[$key]*10)/$fullWidth*10;
        $closest = getClosest($percentage,$arrayToSearch);
        array_push($columnArrayStripped,$closest);
        array_push($columnArrayNew,$closest.'%');
      }
    }
  }
}
else{
  //generate new equal width Bootstrap layout based on number of columns
  //but only if exploded array does not equal column number
  $columnArrayNew = array();
  if(count($columnArrayStripped) != $cols) {
    // if we cant retrieve widths
    for($i=0;$i<$cols;$i++){
        $percentage = round(intval(1000/$cols))/10;
        array_push($columnArrayStripped, $percentage);
        array_push($columnArrayNew, $percentage.'%');
    }
  }
}

echo 'New clean string: "'.implode(',',$columnArrayStripped).'"'."\n";

echo 'New percentage string: "'.implode(',',$columnArrayNew).'"'."\n";

function getClosest($search, $arr) {
   $closest = null;
   foreach ($arr as $item) {
      if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
         $closest = $item;
      }
   }
   return $closest;
}
```

Output:

```
Original string: "%30,%40,%30,%"
Full width = 100
New clean string: "33.3,41.6,33.3"
New percentage string: "33.3%,41.6%,33.3%"
```

**As you can see 33.3 + 41.6 + 33.3 is more than 100%**. I understand why the result is like that, because it aims for the closest, but **how can I prevent issues like this? My goal is to have the resulting string with valid bootstrap widths but the total must be between 99.7 and 100.3.**

(I tagged with regex as well, incase the answer is there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of initial response(no answers and few views), I ended up solving it myself. But I will leave the best answer unmarked for a while in case there is a good idea on how to solve it with regex.

**Here's my solution**
[phpfiddle demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d33c95b91d72f2322c735c1420c1fa61250c6b2a)

Changed code:

```
if($fullWidth > 0){
  foreach($arrayShortened as $key => $value){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $arrayShortened)) {
      if ($columnArrayOld[$key] == '') {
        break;
      } else {
        $percentage = round($arrayShortened[$key]*10)/$fullWidth*10;
        $closest = getClosest($percentage,$arrayToSearch);
        array_push($columnArrayStripped,$closest);
        array_push($columnArrayNew,$closest.'%');
      }
    }
  }
  echo 'Array sum: '.array_sum($columnArrayStripped)."\n";
  // if max value in array > 100, reduce max value with 8.3
  if(array_sum($columnArrayStripped) > 100){
    $maxKey = array_search(max($columnArrayStripped),$columnArrayStripped);
    if($maxKey) {
      $columnArrayStripped[$maxKey] -= $arrayToSearch[0];
      $columnArrayNew[$maxKey] = $columnArrayStripped[$maxKey].'%';
    }
  }
}
```